# Add custom html attribute to be rendered for jsf2 component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox />
```

will render a html checkbox.

How do I add a custom attribute 'myAttribute' with value 6 to it so that the result will be:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-myAttribute="6" ... />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no trivial way to achieve this. Unregistered attribtues are completely ignored. Assuming that you're using Mojarra, your best bet is to extend Mojarra's `CheckboxRenderer` with a custom one wherein you override the `getEndTextToRender()` method which writes the extra attribute. To get it to run, just register it in `faces-config.xml` as a renderer for component family `javax.faces.SelectBoolean` and renderer type `javax.faces.Checkbox`.

An alternative is to delegate the job to some onload JavaScript.